# Auto Indentation Off

Tags: c#, visual-studio, auto-indent

In Visual Studio, when I press Enter, it automatically indents my text, and I don't like that. Is there a way to turn that 'feature' off?

Comment: Why don't you like it? (Note that I am not questioning your opinion, I am just curious).

Comment: +1 - I do like it. But I have a fairly heavy C++ background and would like to be able to type my code in C# so that I get the same "look and feel" of c++ code again, that may sound weird but i really miss c++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Tabs->select none under Indenting or change the tab size to 0

Comment: Thank you, I did already go into the settings. but i obviously missed it. thanks again :) jase.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs -> Indenting

To "none"